# How to know if Google maps is ready to be used?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a simple activity with the follow segment code on it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/title_complex">

   <fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"  
      tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- How to check in MainActivity.java if the map is fully loaded and ready ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can interact with a GoogleMap object, you will need to confirm that an object can be instantiated, and that the Google Play services components are correctly installed on the target device. You can verify that the GoogleMap is available by calling the

> MapFragment.getMap()

or

> MapView.getMap()

methods and checking that the returned object is not null.

An example of a test to confirm the availability of a GoogleMap is shown below. This method can be called from both the **onCreate()** and **onResume()** stages to ensure that the map is always available.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
// Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
if (mMap == null) {
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
    // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
    if (mMap != null) {
        // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.

    }
}
}
```

References - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

Answer (score 1):

Use [GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29).

Comment: Hello @MaciejGórski, thank you for the fast answer, but could You please provide a simple usage, since i've checked the link, but there is not an example.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev See [here](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-v2-demo/blob/master/NewMapsDemo/src/pl/mg6/newmaps/demo/GooglePlayServicesErrorDialogFragment.java) line 51.